# Red Black tree or AVL tree implementation in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, tree, guava

Is there any `Red Black Tree` /`AVL Tree data` structure implementation in Java collections/Guava/Apache Commons library ? If yes , can you point them to me . Basically I am looking for a data structure where the queries should happen in O(lg n)  time . There will also be some updates to the data structure but not quite as often as the queries.

Comment: What's wrong with a good old hash table?

Comment: @delnan Yes hashTable could be one of the choices . I would prefer a hash based map like ConcurrentHashMap but still I would like to know if there is any of these two balanced BST datastructures in these commonly used libraries.

Comment: If all you need is a Map (or Set), then go for `HashMap` as it's faster (`O(1)` with a small factor). Forget about `HashTable` as it's quite obsolete. If you need concurrency, take `ConcurrentHashMap`. If you need order, then go for `TreeMap` and don't care about it being RB-Tree or AVL-Tree or Splay-tree or whatever. If you need something else, so please expand your question.

Comment: I mean, Guava's `TreeMultiset` uses an AVL tree internally...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for mentioning about TreeMultiset

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Basically I am looking for a data structure where the queries should
>   happen in O(lg n) time

Use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). It is backed by a [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) so it's access time is `O(logN)` (my emphasis on quote bellow)

> public class TreeMap
>   extends AbstractMap   implements
>   NavigableMap, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted
>   according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator
>   provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides **guaranteed log(n)** time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

Comment: sorry for nitpicking but just to be clear is the base of the logarithm the natural base ( ie e=2.718281828.) or is it simply base 2 ie lg n ?

Comment: Base 2.Why would it be `lnN`?

Comment: because binary logarithms are usually represented by lg n. This is the conventional notation , I believe.

Comment: If it's _O(log n)_, then the base of the logarithm is irrelevant, since a change of base only involves a constant factor difference.

Comment: @Geek generally when talking algorithms log(x) is log base 2 unless otherwise stated. Even if not, the change is mostly irrelevent as Louis Wasserman stated.

Comment: What about avl tree friends, Is not there any default package available for that ?

Comment: @Sagiruddin Mondal:I think you might find something in the google libraries but not part of the core java

Comment: Another interesting fact is that HashMap since Java 8 also uses internally red black trees for badly distributed hash codes. It first compares by hash code and then if the key is comparable the comparison.